# Add Additional Columns to Links Page (TFS 2018)

Tags: tfs

I am trying to add additional columns to the "Links" page as highlighted in yellow, but can't seem to figure out how to do so.  The request is to add columns to show "Assigned To" and "Remaining Work".

I've looked over and attempted following the information here with no luck: [LinksControlOptions XML elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/linkscontroloptions-xml-elements?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=vsts)

[Links Page - TFS 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chTIF.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "no luck"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried on my side and found your can't customize the default links columns, a workaround is creating a new page between `<WebLayout>` and `</WebLayout>` as the following sample in your work item type definition and add `<Column Name="FieldRefName" />` that you want to shows there:

```
<FORM>    
  <WebLayout>
    <Page Label="Links" LayoutMode="FirstColumnWide">
      <Section>
        <Group Label="links">
          <Control Type="LinksControl" Name="links">
            <LinksControlOptions>
              <LinkFilters>
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Reverse" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Reverse" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Duplicate-Forward" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Dependency" />
                <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Related" />
              </LinkFilters>
              <Columns>
                <Column Name="System.State" />
                <Column Name="System.ChangedDate" />
                <Column Name="System.Links.Comment" />
                <Column Name="System.AssignedTo" />
                <Column Name="System.IterationPath" />
              </Columns>
            </LinksControlOptions>
          </Control>
        </Group>
      </Section>
    </Page>
  </WebLayout>
</FORM>
```

[image]