# How to Add additional columns to links page to ExternalLink types

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

How to add columns to ExternalLink on the "Links" page on Azure DevOps Workitem ?

**Answered : Not Possible see answer below**

> Pull Request is not like Code Review Request, it's not a work item
> type, we cannot see it from the exported process template. So, I don't
> think we can customize the columns like the common work item types. –
> Andy Li-MSFT

after going through the following links
[link1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-add-more-columns-to-link-tab/365954)
[link2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-add-more-columns-to-link-tab/365954)
and trying the workaround discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182405/add-additional-columns-to-links-page-tfs-2018)

I have failed to add more columns to links of the type externallink
i have added the following code as described:

```
         <Page Label="Links" LayoutMode="FirstColumnWide">
          <Section>
            <Group Label="links">
              <Control Type="LinksControl" Name="links">
                <LinksControlOptions>
                  <LinkFilters>
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Build" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Integrated in build" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Pull Request" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Branch" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Fixed in Commit" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Fixed in Changeset" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Source Code File" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="Found in build" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="GitHub Pull Request" />
                    <ExternalLinkFilter Type="GitHub Commit" />
                  </LinkFilters>
                  <Columns>
                    <Column Name="System.State" />
                    <Column Name="System.ChangedDate" />
                    <Column Name="System.PullRequest.IsFork" />
                  </Columns>
                </LinksControlOptions>
              </Control>
            </Group>
          </Section>
        </Page>
```

But the results still show only the original columns.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the field/column you added (`<Column Name="System.PullRequest.IsFork" />`) is not a valid work item filed/column. The workaround is only available for work item types due to the columns depend on work item fields.

You need to add a valid work item field/column here. We can get all the available work item fields by calling the [Get Work Item REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1&tabs=HTTP) with parameter `$expand=Fields` added in the URL from a specific work item.

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=Fields&api-version=4.1
```

For example, the following screenshots shows all the available fields for my `Task` work item. (It depends on how you defined the fields, if you defined a custom field, you can also see it from the response body.):

[image]

After that, we can add the columns (`System.CreatedBy` and `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority` for example in this sample)

[image]

Then check the behavior in a `Task` work item:
[image]

Please note that, `Pull Requests` is not a work item type. We cannot get valid work item fields by calling the [Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request-by-id?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1&tabs=HTTP) REST API. In this case, I don't think we can customize the columns like the common work item types.

Comment: when getting the pull request json - there is no "fields" in the json  . Pull Request Is not a workitem type ?

Comment: @galsi Pull Request is a special work item type, Pull requests (PRs) are a way to change, review, and merge code in a Git repository on Azure Repos. It's not like other common work item types. See [Track work with different work item types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/about-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=cmmi-process#track-work-with-different-work-item-types) and [pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/about-pull-requests?view=azure-devops) for details.

Comment: after looking in the documentation i don't see any option to get fields from pull request. maybe you have any link to example. ?

Comment: @galsi Well, checked again, `Pull Request` is not like `Code Review Request`, it's not a work item type, we cannot see it from the exported process template. So, I don't think we can customize the columns like the common work item types.